# Return json text/msg from the php web service

Tags: php, json, web-services

I have a php web service that takes the request from android/iphone app and uses the input to find the appropriate data from the mysql database. The result is encoded back to json. How can I return the json txt/msg to the android/iphone app. Please help?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo (json_encode ($data_to_send));
```

Comment: You forgot to set the content type.

Comment: this code will only convert the database result(in array) to json. I want to return the json txt to the corresponding mobile. The mobile app is used simultaneously by many users.

Comment: @NeerajDangol That's how you do it.  (plus sending the right content headers as Tomalak said). Echoing sends to the client.

Answer (score 0):

**short answer :** 
Use [json_encode();](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

**long answer :**

Don't forget headers :

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Beware of errors, don't echo them, or echo them in json with json_encode()
So, you need to configure PHP (or at least this page) :

- not to show errors and to log them
- handle errors as array or directly in json